# Stopping a function after completion

Tags: ios, swift, download

I have a function that after I call it once, it keeps constantly calling the function (once the for loop is done with stocks.count, the function will start all over again from 0 to reach stocks.count in an endless loop) and accessing the http which causes the http to stop responding after a couple of minutes and then crashing the app. I have tried adding a timer and even performing a segue after a function is performed (it changes pages but still the function keeps calling the http). But nothing makes the function stop. I would appreciate any help as have been stuck on this issue 3 weeks :(

I call the function as follows:

```
self.downloadStockPrice({ () -> () in
            }, stocks: stocks)
```

And this is the function itself:

```
func downloadStockPrice(completed: DownloadComplete, stocks: [Stock]) {

        for x in 0 ..< stocks.count {
            let stock = stocks[x].stock
            let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22\(stock)%22)&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&format=json")!
            let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
                (data, response, error) -> Void in

                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

                if (statusCode == 200) {
                    print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

                    do{

                        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
                        if let queryDict = json["query"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                            if let resultsDict = queryDict["results"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                if let quoteDict = resultsDict["quote"] as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                                    let bidString = quoteDict["Bid"] as? String
                                    DataService.ds.REF_BASE.child("stocks").child(stock).child("lastPrice").setValue(Float(bidString!))
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }catch {
                        print("Error with Json: \(error)")
                    }

                }
            }

            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your issue isn't clear. Are you saying that your request is being make more often than the number of values in your `stocks` array? Please clarify your issue.

Comment: Yes. So once the for loop reaches the stocks.count, it will start again from 0 to stocks.count in an endless loop.

Comment: That's not being caused by any code you've posted. What debugging have you done to trace the cause of this issue?

Comment: `print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")`
keeps printing on the console more than the 13 stocks that I have in the dictionary

Comment: That doesn't help though. You need to see what keeps calling `downloadStockPrice`.